# Does primeNg 8 support Angular 7?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am planning to use primeNG 8 that fixes a calendar bug in angular 7.

Right now, we are using version 7.1.3 with angular 7 in our project. To fix the calendar bug I need to upgrade to primeNG 8. On the official notes there is no mention that 'We should' upgrade to Angular 8. Many answers in google suggested to upgrade Angular version accordingly.

I want to confirm if the upgrade of primeNg needs an upgrade of Angular as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeng release a new future related to angular version an example primeng 7 release after angular 7 was released and it use some future related to angular 7 ,so in case of primeng 8 was released after angular 8 has been released to upgrade primeng component to be sync with angular version, so you need to upgrade to the new version of angular .

*primeng package.json*

```
devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.1.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "primeflex": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "2.0.0",
    "prismjs": "1.15.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "quill": "1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "web-animations-js": "angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
}
```